# How to create html bar chart with solid fill?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bar-chart

Any help is greatly appreciated to get the html control like this below

[image]

I was trying with jQuery but with no luck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code you've tried then we'll help.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Any code?

Comment: I was struggling with jQuery to get the desired results so nothing great to be shared here. But after digging what I can see is html <meter> tag which can be used for such type of control. Challenge now is to get the meter to show vertical and with gradient fill.

Comment: You can style the meter element, but it is not going to look the same on every browser. https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/ Probably be best to build it with elements stacked. You can pull something off with gradient. There are tricks to make grid lines also. The easiest solution is make an image and clip it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#specify").change(function() {
 $("#bar").height($(this).val() * 2);
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: gray;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#bar {
  /* Gradient Creator */
  background: rgb(75,158,31); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(75,158,31,1) 0%, rgba(252,241,30,1) 50%, rgba(255,30,30,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(75,158,31,1) 0%,rgba(252,241,30,1) 50%,rgba(255,30,30,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(75,158,31,1) 0%,rgba(252,241,30,1) 50%,rgba(255,30,30,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4b9e1f', endColorstr='#ff1e1e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  width: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="specify" type="number" max="100" min="0">
<div id="container">
  <div id="bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

What is happening here is that when the input box changes, it changes the height of the bar.